# Screen Keeps Blinking/Flickering after waking up from lock

Tags: 20.04, login, intel-graphics, screen, vga

After waking up the machine from lock , its starts flickering/blinking with black backlight for some times (from 20 seconds to 5 mins) and then shows enter password screen to login.

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04

Following is my hardware information along with a short video what happens

Hardware Information :

System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Vostro 15-3568 v: N/A serial: 
Mobo: Dell model: 01Y1RD v: A00 serial:  UEFI: Dell v: 01.08.00 date: 03/23/2017

CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-7200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 3072 KiB
flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 21599
Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 802 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1366x768~48Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes

Video Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v8d1vnPz9JNqmU3zCiKcXZZCgmHyjgJ2/view?usp=sharing

Video Link : https://youtu.be/XPfYNbduPig

Comment: @Nmath have updated the video link with Youtube video , anyone can view that

Comment: +1 thanks for posting this. I have the same problem but with 3 monitors on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.8.0-50-generic, and 5.8.16-050816-generic. Are you using pre-built kernel from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ ? Same as me though. If so, it might take part in the factors as those are non-support kernel for Ubuntu.

Comment: @haxpor , thanks but now i have shifted to windows as i got fed up due to this issue , this seems to be my machine issue or may be kernel issue as you said